# NSString hex and decimal output?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dec:%qi, hex:%qX", 1, 1];

yields

dec: 4294967297, hex:BFFFD438000...

??? why ???

thanks

if I use %d and %d, I get 1 and 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

q means 64-bit, so you have to pass 64-bit parameters, e.g. 1LL or 1ULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dec:%i, hex:%x", 1, 1];`